# How do we promote the site?

Tags: discussion

Where's the best place to promote the site? That's what we're gonna need to really drag in a lot of people pretty quickly. Are there magazines that we need to buy ad-space in or is there a specific conference that it would be good to help out at?

Comment: Right now this is private only, so not much need to promote yet.

Comment: No, but it's only private for 1 week. SEI has funding now and can do this if we can build a list. It takes months to figure this stuff out sometimes, so I wanted to ask ahead of time. Had someone asked me on dba _early_ I could've gotten some sponsorships at local events, so I wanted to ask early.

Comment: Point taken :-)

Comment: Ah but yours too sir.

Answer (score 7):

IEEE has a [Signal Processing Society](http://www.signalprocessingsociety.org/) that has a [list of conferences](http://www.signalprocessingsociety.org/conferences/upcoming-conferences/) as well as a [magazine](http://www.signalprocessingsociety.org/publications/publications-home/). This is probably the most focused audience that could be targeted.

Comment: Great idea! I just submitted a short note to the [electronic newsletter](http://signalprocessingsociety.org/newsletter/).

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget the most obvious method of promoting your site —

The best way to tell people about this site is to link to interesting *questions*. Keep the quality high; Most of the network's largest spikes in traffic were simply passing around links to particularly interesting questions!

[**A Recipe to Promote Your Site**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/a-recipe-to-promote-your-site/)

Use those social bookmarking tools!

[image]

Comment: Yup, but that only gets the ones on the social networks. Sometimes you need to reach the print-press-only crowd, which this group is going to have more of. Also the likes of the MAKE crowd (makers are awesome people)

Comment: jcolebrand φ: I didn't imply that question-sharing was the *only* way to promote the site. But it *has* been the most *successful* at bringing in traffic; The most successful way *by far*.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't mean to make it that you were implying that was the only way, I was offering a counterpoint. Yes, most of the people on the internet are on social networks, so social network growth and outreach is a great way to get people's attention in the first place.